# Insert a period before the last two characters of a sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have a column in sql and I need to insert a "." before the last two characters. The column is not fixed length. Can someone help me go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to change a column name or data in the column?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with an UPDATE and SUBSTRING.

```
UPDATE table
SET column = (SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, LEN(column)-2) 
              + '.' 
              + SUBSTRING(column, LEN(column)-1, LEN(column))
```

If you would like to check what the query will do to your column, just use:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(column, 1, LEN(column)-2) 
    + '.' 
    + SUBSTRING(column, LEN(column)-1, LEN(column))
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks messy but this should do it:

```
SELECT LEFT(COL_NAME, LEN(COL_NAME)-1)+'.'+RIGHT(COL_NAME,1)
FROM Table
```

Or if you want to update the value in the database rather than just the output

```
Update Table 
SET COL_NAME = LEFT(COL_NAME, LEN(COL_NAME)-1)+'.'+RIGHT(COL_NAME,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sp_rename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) like this:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.DatabaseName.ColumnName', 'ColumnNa.me', 'COLUMN';
```

If you need to apply this to multiple columns, then I would suggest using the substring method.  No real use to do it for just one `UPDATE` on a column.

Comment: I am not sure, but  I think the op wants the value in the column to be modified, not the name of the column.

Comment: Well, he never mentioned tuples or rows - only columns.  Up to interpretation I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear. If you are trying to insert `. before last 2 characters` into the `column data`, you could use `STUFF()` function.

For ex:

```
Declare @s varchar(50) = '12345678'
Select Stuff(@s, Len(@s)-1, 0, '.')
--> 123456.78
```

Applying to your table query:

```
Select Stuff(yourCol, Len(yourCol)-1, 0, '.')
From yourTable
```

Please note that *If* `Len(yourCol)` *is less than* `2`, a null string will be returned.